# Autoslider (Vanilla JS) not working on IOS

Tags: javascript, html, css

So I created a slider that changes its slide every 5th second.
It is working on Google Chrome as well as Firefox but it doesn't work on Safari (Desktop). On **IOS** Mobile it doesn't work on either Browser which is really weird since I checked the Settings on every Browser. I'm running the newest version and I have no idea why it wouldn't work.

I created a fiddle so you can test it out aswell:

https://jsfiddle.net/yanisdeplazes/4nLbfv58/3/

**HTML:**

```
<section id="slider-section">
    <div class="slider-container">
        <div class="slider-wrapper">
            <div class="slider">
                <img class="slider__image" style="background-color:blue;">
                <div class="slider__text">
                    <h1>Title 1</h1>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="slider">
                <img class="slider__image" style="background-color:red;">
                <div class="slider__text">
                    <h1>Titel 2</h1>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

**JS:**

```
var selection = document.querySelector('.slider-wrapper') == null;
if (selection) {

} else {

    var i = 0;
    const track = document.querySelector('.slider-wrapper');

    function autoslider() {
        var i = 0;
        var time = 5000; // set auto slide time
        const slides = Array.from(track.children); // get Slide as Array
        let arrayLength = slides.length;
        while (i <= arrayLength) {
            (function(i) {
                if (i != slides.length) {
                    setTimeout(function() {
                        const slideWidth = slides[0].getBoundingClientRect().width; // get Slide Width
                        track.style.transform = 'translateX(-' + i * 100 * slideWidth / window.innerWidth + 'vw)';
                    }, time * i)
                } else {
                    setTimeout(function() {
                        autoslider();
                    }, time * i)
                }
            })(i++)
        }
    }

    autoslider();

}
```

**CSS:**

```
:root {
    --sizeslider: 1200px;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 1300px) {
    :root {
        --sizeslider: 1000px;
    }
}
.slider-container {
    max-width: 100vw;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: auto;
}
@media (min-width: 1300px) {
    .slider-container {
        width: var(--sizeslider);
    }
}
.slider-wrapper {
    display: flex;
    transition: all 0.4s ease-in;
}
.slider {
    min-width: 100%;
    display: block;
    padding: 0 25px;
}
@media (max-width: 1300px) {
    .slider {
        padding: 0;
    }
}
.slider__image {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    object-fit: cover;
}
.slider__text {
    margin-top: 40px;
    width: 100%;
}
@media (min-width: 1920px) {
    .slider__image {
        width: calc(var(--sizeslider) / 1.8) !important;
    }
}
@media (min-width: 1100px) {
    .slider {
        padding: unset;
        justify-content: center;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: row;
    }
    .slider:nth-child(2n) {
        flex-direction: row-reverse;
    }
    .slider__image {
        width: calc(var(--sizeslider) / 2 - 50px);
        padding: 0px 50px 0px 0px;
        height: 100%;
    }
    .slider__text {
        width: calc(var(--sizeslider) / 2);
        padding: 0px 50px;
    }
    .slider:nth-child(2n) .slider__text {
        text-align: right;
    }
    .slider:nth-child(2n) .slider__image {
        padding: 0px 0px 0px 50px;
    }
}
```

Thank you for your Answers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Safari doesn't like having variables outside of a function that it uses in a function.

So the simple solution to make it work would be putting the variable inside the function.

```
var i = 0;

function autoslider() {
    const track = document.querySelector('.slider-wrapper');
    var i = 0;
    var time = 5000; // set auto slide time
    const slides = Array.from(track.children); // get Slide as Array
    let arrayLength = slides.length;
    while (i <= arrayLength) {
        (function(i) {
            if (i != slides.length) {
                setTimeout(function() {
                    const slideWidth = slides[0].getBoundingClientRect().width; // get Slide Width
                    track.style.transform = 'translateX(-' + i * 100 * slideWidth / window.innerWidth + 'vw)';
                }, time * i)
            } else {
                setTimeout(function() {
                    autoslider();
                }, time * i)
            }
        })(i++)
    }
}

autoslider();
```